# How to Get the Values from a Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access the values from my array and assign each value to a variable which I am going to use later on.  I have a created an array and through the function randomGo() got a random number for the outer array, which returns the pair of numbers.  I want then to assign each value to a variable.  For example if I get the numbers from randomPlaces [0] how to I make var x= 51.528868434293244 and var y= -0.10179429999993772? Thanks! I am only using Javascript and HTML.

```
var randomPlaces = [[51.528868434293244, -0.10179429999993772], [40.70590473669712, -73.9780035], [48.85887766623369, 2.3470598999999766], [53.32443937613261, -6.251694999999927], [41.392700620871764, 2.139299250000022], [41.83401317282514, -87.73215545], [-33.79773327558923, 150.92243254999994], [50.05981411178046, 14.465623900000082], [52.50786264022465, 13.426141949999987], [30.02193806214437, -89.8822859]];

var randomLength = randomPlaces.length;

    function randomGo(){
        var randomValue = randomPlaces[Math.floor(randomPlaces.length * Math.random())];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has only single-dimensional arrays — but the elements in an array can, themselves, also be arrays. That's what you have there. (Well, to the extent that JavaScript's generic arrays [are even arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)...)

So:

```
var x = randomPlaces[0][0];
var y = randomPlaces[0][1];
```

or of course

```
var randomPlace = randomPlaces[0];
var x = randomPlace[0];
var y = randomPlace[1];
```

Breaking it down: `randomPlaces[0]` returns a the first entry in `randomPlaces`, which is a reference to your `[51.528868434293244, -0.10179429999993772]` array. Then we index into that. The value you wanted for `x` was in the first position, so at `[0]`; the value for `y` at the second position, so `[1]`.

If you wanted the values from the second array (`[40.70590473669712, -73.9780035]`), you'd use:

```
var x = randomPlaces[1][0];
var y = randomPlaces[1][1];
```

...and the third array would be at `[2]`, etc.

If you want to get the position randomly, you'd use `Math.random`, which returns a fractional number between `0` and `1` (inclusive of `0`, **ex**clusive of `1`) and multiply it by the length of the array, flooring (rounding down) the result. (Suppose the array has 20 entries and `Math.random()` returns `0.8`: `0.8 * 20 = 16`.) So for instance:

```
var index, randomPlace, x, y;
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomPlace.length);
randomPlace = randomPlaces[index];
x = randomPlace[0];
y = randomPlace[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But what happens if I want the values when the first array position is randomly generated.  I have math.random giving me the first array so I don't know what value I will get.

Comment: @user1876246: I've added a bit about random numbers to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the element?

It seems like you should be able to get 51.528868434293244 by calling RandomPlaces[0][0]
and -0.10179429999993772 by calling RandomPlaces[0][1].

Right now you are just calling for both of the values together, which you might still be able to access by calling randomValue[0] and randomValue[1].

Answer (score 0):

Add this after you get your randomValue:

```
var x = randomValue[0];
var y = randomValue[1];
```